# raspberrypi - Raspbian - FATAL: Module spi-dev not found

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

In setting up my new raspberry pi (CanaKit Raspberry Pi B+ Ultimate), I am getting failures in loading spi-dev.  No other errors occur during boot.

Looking for assistance in resolving this error. Is there a simple update to install the module?

[info] Loading kernel module snd-bcm2835.
[info] Loading kernel module spi-dev.
FATAL: Module spi-dev not found.

Comment: Give some more details, which board is it, what version, are any other errors / warnings seen...

Comment: I received the GoPiGo as a gift 2 weeks ago.  The raspberrypi is a B+.  It came as a kit.  The control board from DexterIndustries.  The raspberrypi from Canakit.  It there is a better place to find the specific details your are looking for let me know.   There are no other errors upon boot up.   I did not notice this error at first, but came across it while diagnosing a different problem I am having in communicating with the smbus.  Here is that error: i2cdetect -y 0
Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-0' or `/dev/i2c/0': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Firmware 3.18.x breaks I2C, SPI, audio, lirc, 1-wire (e.g. /dev/i2c-1, No such file or directory)

The latest firmware implements device tree support. That will have broken things like I2C, SPI, and 1-wire bus.
    For fuller details see http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=675658#p675658
Summary:
    Add one or more of the following to your /boot/config.txt and reboot.

For I2C
 Add

dtparam=i2c1=on (or dtparam=i2c0=on on old models)

And For SPI
Add to end of conf file

dtparam=spi=on

---

At 
/boot/config.txt
paste at end

device_tree_param=i2c0=on,i2c1=on,spi=on

or like this

dtparam=i2c0=on,i2c1=on,spi=on

then all is fine again

greetings from IRC

Dr_Frankenstein

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem with installing wiringPi, than activated SPI with:

```
gpio load spi
```

Hope that helps.